# Counting loop executions

Tags: java, loops, counting

I'd like to count how many times a loop has executed, not sure how I would go about doing so.

I'm using Dr Java, thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Start with how you would write a loop that just prints 1,2,3,4...  then see how to apply that code to this loop.

Comment: add a statement like count++ in the loop, after the loop check the value of count

Answer (score 3):

Before the loop, define a count variable:

```
int count = 0;
```

Somewhere inside the loop, increment that variable:

```
count++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable outside the scope, set it to 0 and increment each time the loop starts:

```
int counter = 0;
do { 
    counter++;
    uNum= TextIO.getlnInt(); 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly different from the other answers...

#### Option 1:

Use a *local* variable

```
int count = 0;
do {
    count++;
    ...
} while ...

// count now equals the number if iterations
```

But this only counts the iterations once. If you call enter the loop again, it will count it again, forgetting the previous iterations.

#### Option 2:

Use an *instance* variable

To cumulatively count the number of iterations - the true "total" - you need to save state between calls to the method:

```
int count;

public void loopMethod() {
    do {
        count++;
    } while ...
    // count equals the total cumulative iterations 

}
```

Using an instance variable also means the count is available to other methods, if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an int to 0 just before the loop executes.  Increment that int by 1 at the top of the loop.  Now the int will always hold the number of loop executions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, add a counter initialized to zero before the `do{}` loop, like this:

```
int count = 0;
```

Then, increment the counter within the loop, like this:

```
...
count+=1;
} while (uNum > gNum || uNum < gNum);
```

Then, after the loop display the value:

```
System.out.println("Count: " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable outside the loop, and initialize it to zero. Within the loop, just increment that variable, and you will get your count!.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable outside the loop such as `int count = 0`. Increment the variable by one at the beginning of the loop, via `count++` or `count = count + 1`